# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Stuck at OpenGL Version 3.0 - Help/Question

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl, mesa

I am using `padoka` PPA.

`glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"` shows

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD JUNIPER (DRM 2.46.0 / 4.8.0-46-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 17.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Running `glxinfo | grep Max` shows

```
Max core profile version: 3.3
Max compat profile version: 3.0
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
```

So this means that I only have OpenGL 3.3 right? From what I've researched, Mesa 17 should have OpenGL 4.1+ no problem, so why am I stuck at such a low version?

About This Computer shows `Gallium 0.4 on AMD JUNIPER (DRM 2.46.0 / 4.8.0-46-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)`

CompizConfig -> OpenGL Plugin -> Z11 Sync Objects shows my card as NVIDIA GEFORCE 6150, which is the onboard card, not the card that is actually in use. My actual in use card (`lspci | grep VGA`) is `Radeon HD 6770` which is `OpenGl 4.1`.

**I'm hoping this is enough information for someone here to let me know if there is something wrong, something I can change/update, or if there's nothing I can do to get OpenGL 4.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with a 5770. Unfortunately, according to [this](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature) page, Evergreen OpenGL compliance should be at 4.1, but a footnote says: "OpenGL 4.1 is currently only supported on CYPRESS, CAYMAN and ARUBA. All other chips are currently limited to OpenGL 3.3," which excludes JUNIPER. So looks like we're out of luck.